Identify a horror movie with a girl on a boat
I remember watching a small piece of a movie in which a girl is on a boat and she keeps on doing the same weird things. She then sees a note that she has written for herself and when she dies, she sees all the bodies of herself lying there. So that means she is doing the same things over and over again. the actress looks like, and maybe even is Amanda Seyfried. The movie is definitely horror movie.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Have you looked at all Amanda Seyfrieds movies on IMDB so you can exclude her? Any other details would be useful, like when did you see this, on what TV channel etc

The movie you are looking for is called Triangle (2009) starring Melissa George
Those are not the bodies of herself but of Sally played by Rachael Carpani.

Oh my god, yes, that's the movie! Sorry for giving a false indicator of Amanda Seyfried...
